# Codename one simulator clear Storage

Tags: codenameone

Is there any way to clear the storage in Codename one simulator ?

This also applies for preferences.

An equivalent to Clear Database in the early WTK simulators.

Will be pretty handy while building the app.

Thanks,

Sanket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard function but just delete the contents of the .cn1 directory in your home folder and you should be set.